# Placing an 8 bit vector into a 16 bit vector

Tags: vhdl

This might be a stupid question, but I'd like to insert a 8 bit vector into a 16 bit vector before shifting it out.

I currently have this:

```
data        <= "000" & DATA_IN & "00000";
```

Which works perfectly, but I want to be able to select the place where the data is placed with generics (or maybe in the future dynamically).

I tried:

```
data        <= ((15 - (start_from_output-1)) DOWNTO (15 - (start_from_output-1) - (channels_in_use-1)) => DATA_IN , OTHERS => '0');
```

but this gives the error:

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:1728 - "E:/Projects/VHDL/PHASED_ARRAY_0-4/switch.vhd" Line 69: Type error near data_in ; current type std_logic_vector; expected type std_ulogic
```

If I simplify it to

```
data        <= (7 DOWNTO 0 => DATA_IN, others => '0');
```

the same error occurs.

Does someone have any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an assignment like:

```
data <= (OTHERS => '0');
data((15 - (val-1)) DOWNTO (15 - (val-1) - (val2-1)) <= data_in;
```

If I understand you correctly it will do the same job, but it will work only inside a process. Outside the process you'll get multiple driver error.